# Filling an empty (NaN) column with 0 or 1 based on if a value is in a list from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Q1': ['A,B', 'A,C', 'A,B', 'B,C', 'A,B,C','C,B,A','B,C,A'],
               'Q2': ['B,A', 'C,A', 'B,C,A', 'A,B', 'A,C', 'B,C','C,B'], 
               'Q3': ['C,A', 'C,B', 'A,B', 'C,B', 'A,B,C','A,B,C','C,A']})

df['Q1'] = df['Q1'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
df['Q2'] = df['Q2'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
df['Q3'] = df['Q3'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))

colQ1 = df["Q1"].explode().unique()
colQ1df = pd.DataFrame(columns = colQ1)

df = pd.concat([df, colQ1df], sort=False)

print(df)
```

I want to fill the new column 'A' with a '1' if column 'Q1' contains 'A' and 0 if it does not.

Comment: Now I am confused, what is expected output? Because `I need to add columns onto the data frame depending on whats in the string. Is this possible without using explode?`

Comment: @jezrael

You have actually answered a bigger question of mine with the code 

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Q1': ['Apple,Bee', 'Apple,Cat', 'Air Slow,B', 'B,C', 'A,B,C','C,B,A','B,C,A'],
               'Q2': ['B,A', 'C,A', 'B,C,A', 'A,B', 'A,C', 'B,C','C,B'], 
               'Q3': ['C,A', 'C,B', 'A,B', 'C,B', 'A,B,C','A,B,C','C,A']})

df = pd.concat([df[x].str.get_dummies(',') for x in df], keys=df.columns, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

You are absolutely amazing my friend and have saved me so much work. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont explode values, better is use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) if need processing each column same way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Q1': ['A,B', 'A,C', 'A,B', 'B,C', 'A,B,C','C,B,A','B,C,A'],
               'Q2': ['B,A', 'C,A', 'B,C,A', 'A,B', 'A,C', 'B,C','C,B'], 
               'Q3': ['C,A', 'C,B', 'A,B', 'C,B', 'A,B,C','A,B,C','C,A']})

df = pd.concat([df[x].str.get_dummies(',') for x in df], keys=df.columns, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
   Q1_A  Q1_B  Q1_C  Q2_A  Q2_B  Q2_C  Q3_A  Q3_B  Q3_C
0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1
1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1
2     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     0
3     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     1
4     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
5     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
6     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1
```

If want each column to separate Dataframe:

```
df1 = df['Q1'].str.get_dummies(',')
print (df1)
 A  B  C
0  1  1  0
1  1  0  1
2  1  1  0
3  0  1  1
4  1  1  1
5  1  1  1
6  1  1  1
```

Comment: df['Q1'].dtype isn't string anymore because he used explode, it is now a list

Comment: @BrunoMello - Yop, answer was edit with explanation.

Comment: I need to add columns onto the data frame depending on whats in the string. Is this possible without using explode?

Comment: @Mish - Accepting answer means it is correct, so the best ask another answerer.

Comment: Again thanks so much for this code. I need to get my head around it and what it means. I was going to spend all night doing each column one by one. This seems to do the whole lot in one go. Really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply:

```
df['A'] = df['Q1'].apply(lambda x: '1' if 'A' in x else '0')
```

Is that it?

Comment: I feel so dumb. This is correct accept 1 instead of '1' but thats minor. Actually my fault because I said '1' instead.

How would i do this without lambda and using the def method?